# I'm getting a seg fault from the following code. I think it has something to do with my function call?

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault, wrapper

This code is supposed to count all nodes using a wrapper function. This is for a circular linked list, so i'm pointing to rear->next with temp and then traverse with temp until temp ==rear.

```cpp
int count_all(node *rear) {
    int count = 0;
    if (!rear)
        return 0;
    if (rear == rear->next)
        return 1;
    return recursive_count_all(rear,count);
}

int recursive_count_all(node *rear,int &count)  {
    if (!rear)
        return 0;

    node * temp = rear->next; 

    if (rear == temp)
        return 1;
    else
        temp = temp->next;

    return recursive_count_all(rear->next, ++count);
}
```

Comment: That's a funny way to define a linked list, `rear == rear->next`; are you sure?

Comment: We just got introduced to circular linked list ADT's a couple days ago. You want to check if rear == rear->next to see if its a one item list.

Comment: The wrapper should be able to call the recursive function directly with the initial value, `return recursive_count_all(rear, 0);`.

Comment: I missed the "circular" part; my bad. You will probably need two `node` in your recursive call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You end up having an infinite recursion, because your conditional return

```cpp
if (rear == temp)
    return 1;
```

is comparing your previous node with the next node and therefore won't return for #nodes > 1. You should break the recursion conditional once you get to the very first node you started with.

So something like this

```cpp
int count_all(node *rear) {
    int count = 0;
    if (!rear)
        return 0;
    if (rear == rear->next)
        return 1;
    return recursive_count_all(rear,rear,count);
}

int recursive_count_all(node* n0, node *rear,int &count)  {
    if (!rear)
        return 0;

    node * temp = rear->next; 

    if (n0 == temp)
        return 1;
    else
        temp = temp->next;

    return recursive_count_all(n0, rear->next, ++count);
}
```